# Can't set ( in the text field using watir-webdriver

Tags: automated-tests, watir-webdriver

I want to set the value of text_field Using watir-webdriver. The value I want to set has opening and closing brackets, ex "Boston (02116)". I am only able to set the value of the closing bracket, and not the opening bracket. Tried all sorts of different things but nothing worked. I'd appreciate any suggestions to resolve this issue.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="search-container">
<div class="label">Search</div>
  <div>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search/js/update" method="get">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    </div>
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.
    </span>
    <input class="tab_header_filter search ui-autocomplete-input" id="search-list" name="project_name" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**watir-webdriver Code**

```
irb 
require 'watir-webdriver'
b=Watir::Browser.new
b.text_field(:id => 'search-list').set "Boston (02116)"
b.text_field(:id => 'search-list').to_subtype.set "Boston (02116)"
b.input(:class => 'tab_header_filter search ui-autocomplete-input').to_subtype.value = "Boston (02116)"
b.div(:id =>'search-container').div(:index => 1).input(:index=>1).to_subtype.set "Boston (02116)"
```

I have tried several variations of the above commands and all of them inserted Boston 02116) in the text field. I can't get Boston (02116) in there. Any thoughts?

Comment: Using just your html/watir code, the "(" is getting inputted for me. Did you try running your code against just the html snippet your provided? If it works, then I would guess that there is something application specific causing the "(" to be ignored.

Comment: Here's a tip, why don't you give the link to the actual site so I don't have to read your html and can inspect the page. I have to do more work answering your question than I'd ever have to do with watir